# extract column names as a vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`:

```r
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
1   2   3   4   5
...
...
```

and I have to do this operation:

```r
pivot_data <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"), 
               names_to = "var", values_to = "score")
```

but instead of having `cols = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")` I want to replace it by a compact function or something in case let's say I have 1000 columns. How to do that?

Like this?

`cols = colnames(df)`

Comment: As a reminder, it's good to check the `?pivot_longer` help page when you have questions about the function. There are examples that use the `everything()` help to indicate all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just use `gather`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_data <- gather(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

To include all the columns use `everything()`.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_data <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "score")
```

To include columns that start with `'x'` use `starts_with`.

```
pivot_data <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('x'), names_to = "var", values_to = "score")
```

To include columns that has `'x'` followed by a number use `matches`-

```
pivot_data <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('x\\d+'), names_to = "var", values_to = "score")
```